# Appengine User and Google Identity Toolkit

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-identity-toolkit

What is suggested way to utilise the Google Identity Toolkit with Appengine. In such a way that all request are validated for authorised Client(device) and also the authorised User.

Comment: hi, did you manage to find how it's done?

Comment: no not yet, hope they will deprecate the Identity Toolkit soon.